# how to compute "m" in Jaro Winkler distance?

Tags: string, algorithm

For computing Jaro distance of two string we use this equation:

dj = 1/3 (m/|s1| + m/|s2| + (m-t)/m)

How should I compute "m" for two strings in this equation?

If "m" is the difference between two strings, why does the example at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance#Example) for the two string "MARTHA" and "MARHTA", m is 6. I think it should be 1, because the difference between the strings is 1 not 6! Am I right?

Comment: m is the number of matching characters between two strings which is 6 in your case

Comment: Wikipedia's example (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance#Example) does a great job of walking through your exact problem, so what's the real issue?

Comment: @ AndyG: I can't understand how to compute m and t! in Wikipedia's example, for "MARTHA" and "MARHTA", m=6, means all the same characters, but for "CRATE" and "TRACE", m=3, that means all the same characters in the same order, so for "MARTHA" and "MARHTA", m should be 4 because T and H are not in the same order in two strings!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`m` is the number of characters that are shared between the two strings regardless of their positions and that their distance is not farther than `d = floor(max(len(String1), len(String2)) / 2) - 1` (thanks Michael Foukarakis). This is 6 for `MARTHA` and `MARHTA`.

`t` is the number of characters that are shared but are in different positions, divided by 2. In this case , 2 characters (`H` and `T`) are shared but are in different positions so `t = 2/2 = 1`.

Comment: Not entirely correct - two characters are matching only if they are the same and not farther than `d = floor(max(len(String1), len(String2)) / 2) - 1`.

Comment: ok, but there is another example here that computed m and t in different way, for "CRATE" and "TRACE" as you said, m should be 5, because all characters are shared between two strings, but m=3! I don't know why?! and t should be 1 (C and T) but t=0! could you please explain it for me?

Comment: @soodehp see Michael's correction. There is a distance restriction, which in the case of CRATE/TRACE is `d = floor(5/2)-1 = 1`. Thus, C and T are too far so they are not considered.

Comment: does `t` share the distance constraint too?